# XSLT move nodes to a new created element

Tags: xslt

struggle to find a way to do followings by using XSLT, thanks for any help. RJ

input:

```
<root>
    <a>a1</a>
    <b>b1</b>
    <c>c1</c>
    <a>a2</a>
    <b>b2</b>
    <c>c2</c>
    ...
</root>
```

output:

```
<root>
    <item>
        <a>a1</a>
        <b>b1</b>
        <c>c1</c>
    </item>
    <item>
        <a>a2</a>
        <b>b2</b>
        <c>c2</c>
    </item>
    ...
</root>
```

Comment: Hello, and welcome to StackOverflow! Although it is always good to include your input and output samples, which you have done, it would also help alot if you did try to explain the rules of the transformation, otherwise folk may have to make assumptions. Showing the XSLT you currently have, if possible, also helps. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please note that tags aren't keywords.  That is, sticking every possible word that might apply to your problem as a tag isn't going to be helpful to others trying to find your question.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and I will follow the rule for next post, Cheers, RJ.

Comment: Did a test run on my data and shown as you list below - the only problem is the first item has an extra entry <a>a2</a>, which should be part of second item only.  How can I get rid of it?  Thanks, RJ.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking to 'group' the elements into 'items' using the **a** element as the first element of the group, one way is to use an **xsl:key** to group elements by the first-most preceding **a** element

```
<xsl:key name="items" match="root/*" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::a[1])" />
```

Then you can simply match the **a** elements, and copy all the elements looked up in the key

```
<xsl:copy-of select="key('items', generate-id())" />
```

Here is the full XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:key name="items" match="root/*" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::a[1])" />

   <xsl:template match="/root">
      <root>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="a" />
      </root>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="a">
      <item>
         <xsl:copy-of select="." />
         <xsl:copy-of select="key('items', generate-id())" />
      </item>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your sample XML, the following is output:

```
<root>
   <item>
      <a>a1</a>
      <b>b1</b>
      <c>c1</c>
      <a>a2</a>
   </item>
   <item>
      <a>a2</a>
      <b>b2</b>
      <c>c2</c>
   </item>
</root>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="text()"/>

    <xsl:template match="/root">
        <root>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="a">
        <item>
            <a><xsl:value-of select="text()"/></a>
            <b><xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::b/text()"/></b>
            <c><xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::c/text()"/></c>
        </item>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```